# Any way to optimize testing each bullet for each enemy in shoot em' ups?

Tags: xna-4.0, shoot-em-up

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to increase the collision check efficiency of a system of n objects?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24286/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-collision-check-efficiency-of-a-system-of-n-objec)

Lately I have been making a shoot em' up, and for collision detection I would use `foreach` loops, testing each bullet for each ship, like so:

```
foreach (Bullet bullet in BulletOnScreen.ToList())
{
    foreach (EnemyShip ship in Enemies.ToList())
    {    
        if (bullet.BulletRectangle.Intersects(ship.Rectangle))
        {
            ship.ReceiveDamage(bullet.Damage);
        }
    }
}
```

But is there a better way to check for collision?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24286/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-collision-check-efficiency-of-a-system-of-n-objec/24289)

Comment: Unless you have a huge number of both enemies and bullets I doubt that this would case a performance issue. However, if it is mostly likely the best way to optimize would be to leverage characteristics of your game-play to reduce the numbers of checks. However, for us to help you with that we need more details about the game-play.

Comment: At a high level it's an exact dupe of the other question.  But one point I would make: Why are you `ToList`ing your collections?